# Как передать данные из json в js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

У меня есть 3 файла json, например:
1.json,
2.json,
3.json

В этих файлах хранятся 3 разных языка. Как мне получить все 3 файла в объект?
я делаю так:

```js
let arrLang = {
    'ru': $.getJSON('../locales/1.json'),
    'en': $.getJSON('../locales/2.json'),
    'ro': $.getJSON('../locales/3.json')
}
```

Comment: И какая у вас ошибка?

Comment: у меня там ещё куча скрипта, например по кнопке он переводит страницу с ру, на англ. До этого весь перевод был в формате js в объекте, и всё переводилось. Сейчас надо распределить языки по json файлам и оттуда переводить. И у меня затык.

Answer (score 1):

```
let arrLang = {
    'ru': null,
    'en': null, 
    'ro': null 
};

$.getJSON('../locales/ru.json', (data) => arrLang.ru = data);
$.getJSON('../locales/en.json', (data) => arrLang.en = data);
$.getJSON('../locales/ro.json', (data) => arrLang.ro = data);
```